# Charts not being displayed while selecting from sideBarMenu and radioButton in Shiny

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am not sure why the charts are not being displayed. All I want is the user must select a menuSubItem from the sidebarMenu and select a choice in the radioButton, when these are selected, respective tabs in the dashboardBody must be displayed. When I tried to execute this code, nothing is working, and no error is thrown. Please help. Also suggest if any alternative coding can be done to get this done.
Thanks,

```
ui <-  dashboardPage(#skin="purple-light",
dashboardHeader(title="Testing"),
dashboardSidebar(width=200, 
               sidebarMenu(id= "sbar",verbatimTextOutput("text1"),verbatimTextOutput("text2"),
                           menuItem("Menu1", tabName = "MenuTab1",startExpanded = TRUE,
                                    menuSubItem("Sub Menu1", tabName = "sub1"),
                                    menuSubItem("Sub Menu2", tabName = "sub2")),
                           menuItem("Menu2", tabName= "MenuTab2",startExpanded = TRUE,
                                    menuSubItem("Sub Menu3", tabName = "sub3"),
                                    menuSubItem("Sub Menu4", tabName = "sub4")))),

  dashboardBody(radioButtons("rb1",label=NULL, choices = c("choice1","choice2"), selected=NULL),
      tabItems(
              tabItem("sub1",title= "Tab1",fluidRow(plotOutput("plot1"),plotOutput("plot3"))),
              tabItem("sub2",title= "Tab2",fluidRow(plotOutput("plot1"),plotOutput("plot2"))),
              tabItem("sub3",title= "Tab3",fluidRow(plotOutput("plot1"),plotOutput("plot3")))))) 

server <- function(input,output){
 set.seed(1234)
 observe(input$sbar)
 p1 <- reactive({
      req(input$rb1)
      req(input$sbar)

      if (      input$sbar == "sub1" && input$rb1 =="choice1" ){
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub1" && input$rb1 =="choice2") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub2" && input$rb1 =="choice1") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("black"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub2" && input$rb1 =="choice2") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub3" && input$rb1 =="choice1") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("black"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub3" && input$rb1 =="choice2") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub4" && input$rb1 =="choice1") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("yellow"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub4" && input$rb1 =="choice2") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("orange"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else {return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("green"),binwidth=0.2))}
    })
 p2 <- qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2)
 p3 <- qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("yellow"),binwidth=0.2)

observe(input$sbar)
output$text1      <- renderText(print(input$rb1))
output$text2      <- renderText(print(input$sbar))
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({p1})
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({p2()})
output$plot3 <- renderPlot({p3})
```

shinyApp(ui, server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wish to see 4 different tabs with their own plots, define four reactive plots.
Then in each tab you have two choices.
Please see the code below.

```
 ui <-  dashboardPage(#skin="purple-light",
    dashboardHeader(title="Testing"),
    dashboardSidebar(width=200, 
                     sidebarMenu(id= "sbar",verbatimTextOutput("text1"),verbatimTextOutput("text2"),
                                 menuItem("Menu1", tabName = "MenuTab1",startExpanded = TRUE,
                                          menuSubItem("Sub Menu1", tabName = "sub1"),
                                          menuSubItem("Sub Menu2", tabName = "sub2")),
                                 menuItem("Menu2", tabName= "MenuTab2",startExpanded = TRUE,
                                          menuSubItem("Sub Menu3", tabName = "sub3"),
                                          menuSubItem("Sub Menu4", tabName = "sub4")))),
    
    dashboardBody(radioButtons("rb1",label=NULL, choices = c("choice1","choice2"), selected=NULL),
                  tabItems(
                    tabItem("sub1",title= "Tab1",fluidRow(plotOutput("plot1"))),
                    tabItem("sub2",title= "Tab2",fluidRow(plotOutput("plot2"))),
                    tabItem("sub3",title= "Tab3",fluidRow(plotOutput("plot3"))),
                    tabItem("sub4",title= "Tab3",fluidRow(plotOutput("plot4")))
                    ))) 
  
  server <- function(input,output){
    set.seed(1234)
    observe(input$sbar)
    p1 <- reactive({
      req(input$rb1)
      req(input$sbar)
      
      if (      input$sbar == "sub1" && input$rb1 =="choice1" ){
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub1" && input$rb1 =="choice2") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2))
      }
    })
    p2 <- reactive({
      req(input$rb1)
      req(input$sbar)
      
      if (input$sbar == "sub2" && input$rb1 =="choice1") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("green"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub2" && input$rb1 =="choice2") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("brown"),binwidth=0.2))
      }
    })
    p3 <- reactive({
      req(input$rb1)
      req(input$sbar)
      
      if (      input$sbar == "sub3" && input$rb1 =="choice1" ){
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("yellow"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub3" && input$rb1 =="choice2") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("orange"),binwidth=0.2))
      }
    })
    p4 <- reactive({
      req(input$rb1)
      req(input$sbar)
      
      if (input$sbar == "sub4" && input$rb1 =="choice1") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("purple"),binwidth=0.2))
      }else if (input$sbar == "sub4" && input$rb1 =="choice2") {
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("black"),binwidth=0.2))
      }
    })
    
    
    observe(input$sbar)
    output$text1      <- renderText(print(input$rb1))
    output$text2      <- renderText(print(input$sbar))
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({p1()})
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({p2()})
    output$plot3 <- renderPlot({p3()})
    output$plot4 <- renderPlot({p4()})
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I did change as your suggestion, but the charts are not being plotted yet, nor I could see the verbatimTextOutput(text1) or text2.

Comment: The fact is I need to use the menuSubItem and radioButton values to display tabItem with title tab1 or tab2 or tab3 or tab4.... in dashboardBody. Each of these tabs in realtime have fluidRows with several charts. So if I use the above suggestion, this would only satisfy tab1 selection in dashboarBody. How could I use the if condition to display the desired tabs instead of just one tab (i.e. tab1). Please help.